# Count records in QueryLocator?

Tags: batch, count, querylocator

For counting recording of an sObject I would write ...

> > Select count() from obj;

But how do I find out the total records in Database.QueryLocator?

Comment: it returns a list. you can check `list.size()`

Answer (score 1):

Use **Database.countquery()** method before **database.querylocator**.

```
String QueryString = 'SELECT count() FROM Account';
    Integer i = Database.countQuery(QueryString);
```